# In Typescript, how do you type an object when it's properties are not know beforehand?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, types, axios

I'm relatively new to typescript so pardon me if I'm missing something obvious. I'm using typescript with ReactJS and I am trying to define types for an API response.

The API docs say there's a `meta` property which is an object but it's key/values can can't be predicted. i.e

```
{
  ...
  meta: {
    property1: value1 //(can be string/number/array)
    property2: value2
    .
    .
    .
    propertyN: valueN
  }
}
```

How do I type this effectively? My eslint complaints when I try `{ meta: object }` so I'm assuming that's no good.

Comment: you can use `any` or `unknown` as the type;  in general, `unknown` is more restrictive, and if you are thinking of using `any`, try `unknown` first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have no idea what it's going to contain, other than that it's going to be an object, you can use:

```
{ [key: string]: unknown };
```

It's not exactly *effective* - you'll have to do further explicit type-narrowing on every property value, but at least it's type *safe* (unlike `any`).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it `can be string/number/array`, just define it like that:

```js
type MetaType = { [key: string]: string | number | any[] };
```